# SP List JSON Body Configure Layout - how to add Modified (date/time)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

I am configuring the display of the body using JSON of a SP List with a number of  single line of text fields.

Now I want to make visible the Modified (read-only Date Time) field which I added as a column to the list (so Modified is included in list view settings (display is enabled)).

1. I do not see the Modified in Edit Columns? how can it be added?
2. I entered "Modified" in body / JSON but it not visible

```
{
    "displayname": "Entry",
        "fields": [
            "Modified"
        ]
}
```

I prefer a way in JSON (if not then I need to use Power Apps).

Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is **not** possible to show SharePoint out of the box fields like Created, Modified, Created By, Modified By, etc. on list forms in modern experience using JSON.

You can add those by customizing the list form using Power Apps.