# the value created by in new entry form

Tags: sharepoint-online

i´m not able the insert the created by value  in the new entry form with json.

is there a way or is it not possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to insert the created by value in the new entry form with json.

You can add it by customizing the list form using Power Apps:

[image]

Similar issue:
[SP List JSON Body Configure Layout - how to add Modified (date/time)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/294217/sp-list-json-body-configure-layout-how-to-add-modified-date-time)